# pyqt event trigger on click of minimze button

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, minimize

I've figured out how to trigger an event when the window changes, but this happens when I'm reading window information from the database, and I want to write to the database when the window is reduced, so, I would like to trigger my event based on clicking the reduce button as opposed to just any time the window changes.

Comment: Both of these are good examples, but perhaps I need to explain a little more. When my sub window state changes (minimize or maximize, showEvent or hideEvent) I need to update a database to record the state. Both of these options will work well for minimizing the window, however, the show event happens when the window is created and I'm reading from the database, so, when I trigger my write to database on the showEvent I get a database lock. I may have to figure this out with a better sequence of events rather than trying to find a way to trigger event on the click of minimize/show button.

Comment: I've updated my answer to trap both the minimize and restore change-events (which occur only _after_ the window has been created). But I'm not convinced this is right way to implement what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The script below works on both Linux and Win XP (and probably OSX, but I can't test it):

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)

    def changeEvent(self, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.WindowStateChange:
            if self.windowState() & QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimized:
                print('changeEvent: Minimised')
            elif event.oldState() & QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimized:
                print('changeEvent: Normal/Maximised/FullScreen')
        QtGui.QWidget.changeEvent(self, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.resize(300, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`QWidget.hideEvent`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#hideEvent) and check for `self.isMinimized()`, because `hideEvent` called when closing window too. Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


class HookMinimize(QWidget):
    def hideEvent(self, event):
        QWidget.hideEvent(self, event)
        if self.isMinimized():
            print "Doing background task"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = HookMinimize()
    window.resize(300, 400)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work on Linux. Also, on Windows, the background task will run again when an already minimised window is closed (which is probably not what is wanted).